# Connotation of the word "pile"

Tags: meaning, connotation

We would like to start an info-service for programmers and we came up with a name:

> Code Pile

How does it sound for native-speakers? Is it ok?

Comment: The extant sense of *piles* to mean ***hemorrhoids*** makes this choice especially untasty.

Comment: @tchrist Yep, found that. +++

Answer (score 3):

The word "pile" sounds like disorganized stuff lying on top of another. Hence, it may not be the best choice for the name of a commercial product.

Comment: Perhaps a code pile is one whose stack has overflowed. :)

Comment: Codestack would be a better name. Unfortunately [someone got there first](http://www.codestack.in).